# How to install Farming Simulator 22 on Raspi with Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, arm, x86

There is a problem with the processor architecture... I guess that Farming Simulator 22 has x86-commands but the raspi hasn't.
Is there any way to make farming simulator work on Linux?

I have a CD-Rom, so no steam or epic games installation.

Comment: Is [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) out of the question?

Comment: Let's even say you get it to run, do you think it's gonna be remotely usable? The minimum requirements for this game is much higher than what you have on any raspberry pi.

Answer (score 3):

There's multiple reasons why this wouldn't work

Looking at the minimum system requirements

> Windows 10 64bit
> Intel Core i5-3330 or AMD FX-8320 or better
> Nvidia Geforce GTX 660, AMD Radeon R7 265 graphics card or better (min 2GB VRAM, DX11/DX12 support)
> 8 GB RAM
> 35 GB free hard drive space

While you can run x86 software wine on linux - using QEMU to translate, its got some overhead.

Even *if* the raspberry pi was x86, which it isn't, the latest and greatest, fully spacced out model is slower than the minimum specifications. An x86 machine with the minimum specs is roughly on par with my old 10 year old former gaming PC (and you might be able to get a used one cheaper than a PI), and that would run circles around it

You have a built in GPU that's not very powerful - and a RPI has no PCIe slots so you can't install one *unless* you're using a compute board with a carrier. That adds to cost *and* you need a GPU and power it, which negates the power savings of a PI.

You don't have SATA or M.2 so you'd be running your game off an *SD CARD*, which if the CPU being slow and the GPU being non existent wasn't a problem, would probably affect performance a great deal.

Basically, you can't, you shouldn't, and its not possible.